# Use npm JavaScript package in Ionic2 TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, npm, ionic2

I started my first project with Ionic2 (TypeScript) and need to use the npm JavaScript package. In my project I use https://github.com/huttarichard/instagram-private-api

I don't understand how can I properly `import` a class instead the `require` and how I should use values in constructor class.

```
var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('someuser');
```

Comment: try `import { v1 } from 'instagram-private-api'`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to /src/
2. Open the assets folder
3. Create a /js/ folder inside assets
4. Copy your .js inside this js folder
5. Goto /src/index.html
6. Add your path  Go to your typescript file of choice and declare var N; N.yourFunction

Greetings